# Java/GAE - Detect if HTTP Response content is HTML?

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, httpresponse

Using Google App Engine, I'm making  request like this:

```
URLFetchService service = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
HTTPResponse response = service.fetch(request);
```

To detect if it returns HTML or not, I'm just stringifying the response and looking for the presence of HTML tags.

```
String responseAsString = new String(response.getContent());

if (responseAsString.contains("<html>")){
    // is html
}
```

What would be a better way to detect if it's HTML or not?

Also, the input url's are not necessarily descriptive like example.com/page.html - the problem is they might be like example.com/mystery

Comment: Check the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService()
            .fetch(new URL("url_to_fetch"));
List<HTTPHeader> headers = response.getHeaders();

for (HTTPHeader h : headers) {
    if (h.getName().equals("Content-Type")) {
        /*
        * could be text/html; charset=iso-8859-1.
        */
        if (h.getValue().startsWith("text/html")) {
            /* TODO do sth. */
        }
    }
}
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPResponse#getHeaders()

Also you can check other [MIME Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type#Type_text).

Comment: This doesn't always work. eg: Some flickr CDNs will return an html page with a content-type of image/jpeg if the image is no longer available to be served. Admittedly, it's their fault, but still...